# Bin multiple R data.table columns by quantiles with NAs in values

Tags: r, data.table

Here's my example code:

```
library(data.table)
library(binr)

DT <- data.table(A=rnorm(100), B=rnorm(100), C=rnorm(100))
na_rows <- sample(DT[,.N], 10)
cols = c("A", "B")
DT[na_rows, (cols):=NA]

DT[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, bins.quantiles, target.bins=5, max.breaks=5), .SDcols=cols]
DT[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, bins.quantiles, target.bins=5, max.breaks=5, na.rm=TRUE), .SDcols=cols]
```

Neither of the last two lines work, giving the following errors respectively:

```
1) Error in quantile.default(x, probs = 0:nbreak/nbreak) : 
  missing values and NaN's not allowed if 'na.rm' is FALSE
2) Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : unused argument (na.rm = TRUE)
```

Desired output is for values in columns A and B to be replaced by integers 1-5, corresponding to quantiles (so the top 1/5 values of each column would be changed to 5, next 1/5 to 4 e.t.c.) and for the NAs to still be NAs

I would like to know how to solve this problem, doesn't have to be the binr library (data.table is probably mandatory, because i need to do this on a lot of rows/columns). Would be grateful for explanations as to why my approach is wrong, too

Comment: where does `bins.quantiles` come from?

Comment: @docendodiscimus edited the post, i forgot to include libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that quantileCut from lsr package kinda does what i want (have to do factor to numeric afterwards, though)

```
library(data.table)
library(lsr)

DT <- data.table(A=rnorm(100), B=rnorm(100), C=rnorm(100))
na_rows <- sample(DT[,.N], 10)
cols = c("A", "B")
DT[na_rows, (cols):=NA]

DT[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, quantileCut, n=5), .SDcols=cols]
DT[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, as.numeric), .SDcols=cols]
```